# DataAnnotation validando propriedade com plugin Javascript. ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, html5, razor, dataannotations

Preciso validar um campo do meu model que possue um editor de texto em `Javascript`. Até ai tudo bem, pois o problema só ocorre no cadastro que eu não recebo no parâmetro da Action "Create" um objeto, e sim um `FormCollection`. No caso do meu Edit, eu recebo um Objeto instanciado, no caso o objeto editado com todas propriedades preenchidas e o DataAnnotation funciona perfeitamente.

Tentei fazer com que meu Create usasse este binding de receber na Action por parâmetro o objeto com as propriedades setadas, funciona, porém meu `ModelState.IsValid` vem sempre falso, pois tem propriedades requeridas que seto dentro desta Action, então o ModelState só verifica quando entra na Action e não se atualiza mais (tentei o `TryUpdateModel()` e não funciona também).

O que eu preciso é saber como fazer funcionar com o FormCollection ou com o Binding, cada um tem seu problema no meu caso. Vou postar o caso e vocês analisam por favor.

Model:

```
public class News
    {
        public int IdNews { get; set; }

        [DisplayName("*Título:")]
        [RegularExpression(@"^[0-9a-zA-Z\-\sãâáàéèêíìîõôóòûúùç]{1,50}$", ErrorMessage = "Apenas letras ou números são aceitos.")]
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Defina o título.")]
        public string Title { get; set; }

        [DisplayName("*Descrição:")]
        [StringLength(5000, MinimumLength = 100, ErrorMessage = "A descrição deve conter no mínimo 100 caracteres e no máximo 5000.")]
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Escreva a descrição.")]
        [UIHint("tinymce_jquery_full"), AllowHtml]        
        public string Description { get; set; }

        [DisplayName("*Data de postagem:")]        
        [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0: dd/MM/yyyy}")]
        public DateTime PostDate { get; set; }

        //[Required(ErrorMessage = "Escreva o nome do Administrador que esta postando.")]
        public string AdminName { get; set; }

        [DisplayName("Selecione uma imagem:")]
        public string ImagePath { get; set; }
    }
```

Action:

```
[HttpPost]
        [ValidateInput(false)]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult Create(FormCollection form)
        {
            News news = new News()
            {
                Title = (form["title"] as string) ?? String.Empty,
                Description = (form["description"] as string) ?? String.Empty,
                PostDate = DateTime.Now,
                AdminName = AdminModel.UserLogged.Name ?? String.Empty,
            };

            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                if (Request.Files["fileUpload"].ContentLength > 0)
                {
                    PhotoController pCon = new PhotoController();
                    news.ImagePath = pCon.NewsFile(Request.Files, news);
                }
                else
                    news.ImagePath = String.Empty;

                using (NewsDAO dao = new NewsDAO())
                {
                    if (dao.SaveNews(news))
                    {
                        ViewBag.AlertMessage = ("Notícia inserida com sucesso!");
                        return View();
                    }
                }
            }
            ViewBag.AlertMessage = "Erro ao inserir notícia.";
            return View(news);
        }
```

View:

```
@model BraveryBranded.ASP.Areas.Admin.Models.News

@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")

    <script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/tinymce/tinymce.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        tinymce.init({
            selector: "textarea",
            plugins: [
            "advlist autolink link lists charmap print preview hr anchor pagebreak spellchecker",
            "searchreplace wordcount visualblocks visualchars code fullscreen insertdatetime media image nonbreaking",
            "save table contextmenu directionality emoticons template paste textcolor"
            ],
            width: 700,
            height: 250,
        });
    </script>

    @if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(ViewBag.AlertMessage))
    {
        <text>
            <script type="text/javascript">
                alert('@Html.Raw(ViewBag.AlertMessage)');
            </script>
        </text>
        ViewBag.AlertMessage = String.Empty;
    }
}

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Nova notícia";
}

<h2>@ViewBag.Title</h2>
<hr />
@using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "News", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

    <fieldset>
        <legend>News</legend>

            @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.IdNews)
        <div class="editor-label">
            *Título:
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Title)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Title)
        </div>
        <br />
        <div class="editor-label">
            Selecione uma imagem (imagem que representa o post na página inicial):
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            <input type="file" name="fileUpload" accept="image/jpg, image/jpeg, image/png" id="file_upload" />
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ImagePath)
        </div>
        <br />
        <div class="editor-label">
            *Descrição (deve conter entre 100 e 5000 caracteres):
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.Description, new { @style="height:180px; width:550px;", @required="required" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Description)
        </div>
        <br />
        <p>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" onclick="return confirm('Revise o nome da galeria antes de confirmar');">Adicionar</button>
        </p>
    </fieldset>
}

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Voltar para a lista", "List", null, new { @class = "btn btn-sm btn-primary" })
</div>
```

Print para ajudar no entendimento:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Outra dúvida também é por que no caso do título, ele "verifica" se esta preenchido antes de entrar no controller e no caso da descrição, ele entra no controller antes? Verifiquei isto com um breakpoint.

Comment: Se você colocar um breakpoint em `if (ModelState.IsValid)` e apontar o mouse em cima do `ModelState`, quais são as variáveis dentro de "Values" que possuem ErrorCount maior que zero?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Isto aqui:

```
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.IdNews)
```

Faz o `ModelState` tentar validar a chave `IdNews`, que não possui valor algum na `Action Create`.

Remova o `hidden` e teste a validação novamente.